# openfire monitor stanza xml message

Tags: java, debugging, openfire, smack

inside openfire admin control panel page, is there any plugin i can use to monitor xml stanza . i know able to monitor it from smack client side, but i want to see it directly from server size, then my client do not need to run in debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Openfire's Admin interface, go to:

Server > Server Settings > Message Audit Policy (or directly to /audit-policy.jsp)